# Ошибка с кодировкой utf-8 в Python

Tags: python, unicode

При запуске скрипта выдается ошибка:

> ```
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc7 in position 0: 
>     invalid continuation byte
> ```

Все работало на винде, но сейчас перешел на убунту и словил ошибку. IDE PyCharm.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-

import vk
import time

token = "8723b7"
session = vk.Session(access_token=token)
api = vk.api.API(session, v='5.80', land='ru')
adres2 = '//home//sergey//Рабочий стол//Alfa-Forex MetaTrader 
4//MQL4//Files//text.txt' #открытая группа

position2 = 0 #открытая группа

with open(adres2) as fh2:
    while True:
        fh2.seek(position2) #открытая группа

        data2 = fh2.read() #открытая группа

        position2 = fh2.tell() #открытая группа

        if data2:
            api.wall.post(owner_id='-11', message=data2)# открытая 
группа

        time.sleep(3)
```

ошибка:

> ```
> /usr/bin/python3.6 /home/sergey/bin/Signal.py
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>  File "/home/sergey/bin/Signal.py", line 39, in <module>
>    data2 = fh2.read() #открытая группа
>  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
>   (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
>  UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc7 in position 
>  0: invalid continuation byte
> ```

Объясните как это исправить?

Comment: не помогло(, осталось точно так же

Comment: Скорее всего файл `text.txt` у вас сохранен в кодировке cp1251. Попробуйте открывать с указанием кодировки: `with open(adres2, encoding='cp1251') as fh2:`

Comment: Все заработало. спасибо!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Все работало на винде, но сейчас перешел на убунту и словил ошибку.

`open()` по умолчанию использует [`locale.getpreferredencoding(False)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.getpreferredencoding) вызов,  который может разные значения возвращать на Windows and Ubuntu (и также возможны разные значения для разных пользователей и/или окружений на этих системах).

На русской Windows, `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)` вероятно ANSI code page возвращает: `cp1251`  кодировку, а на Ubuntu -- `UTF-8`.

Поэтому явно кодировку для файла правильную передайте (вероятно `'cp1251'`):

```
with open(filename, encoding=encoding) as file:
    # use file here
```